# Scroll layout with horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I need to create a 2D view in my Android Application. I tried this with recyclerview inside horizontal scroll view. But I need to create a heading for each item and have to scroll the heading with recyclerview scroll horizontally. Is it possible?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/tablayoutbg">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Sl.No"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msubtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: use NestedScrollView instead of HorizontalScrollView and set layoutmanager of recyclerview

Comment: I need scroll recyclerview horizontally. is it possible with NestedScrollView

Comment: yes its possible.Search for same

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested recyclerview to solve your issue. In the parent recyclerview item take a layout and here set a header for each recyclerview

Comment: I need scroll recyclerview horizontally. is it possible with NestedScrollView

Comment: yes, it is possible. use this code to scroll recyclerview horizontally.

Comment: LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

Comment: recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter_object);

Comment: How to scroll the heading when i scroll recyclerview horizontally?

Comment: When you are using nested recyclerview then parent item contains the header and it is autometically scroll when you scroll parent recyclerview

Comment: see this example : http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: In the previous example, there is no heading scroll with recyclerview

Comment: in that example horizontal scroll under virtical recyclerview. you have to change that direction

Comment: the above example is not working. I need a recycleview like table view. It should need a horizontal and vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have placed recycler view inside horizontal scroll view ??